# Rails 3 AJAX problem - UJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

Ok so here is my setup, I think I have everything set up correctly but for some reason the page isn't displaying the AJAX response.

Basically I have a members list and want to display their "profile" with ajax on the same page.

In views/member/index.html.erb

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
 </tr>

<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= member.name %> &amp; <%= member.sname %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', member, :remote => true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_member_path(member) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'New Member', new_member_path %>

<div id="memberprofile">

</div>
```

In my members controller I have this:

```
def show
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.js
    format.xml  { render :xml => @member }
 end
end
```

Then in my _show.js.rjs I have this

```
page.replace_html('memberprofile', render(@member))
```

Then in my _member.html.erb partial I have this:

```
<h1><%= @member.name %></h1>
```

A few questions:

1) From the console it says "Rendered members/show.html.erb" but I thought it would just render the member partial. why is this?

2) Nothing is happening in the index.html.erb page when the ajax call goes out. I thought having the div hook plus the javascript file would do the trick...

Thanks guys

Comment: Try renaming `_show.js.rjs` to `show.js.rjs`, It looks like your `format.js` is rendering default `show.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new partial that only display the profile of member. Lets say the partial name is _member.html.erb
in your index file do:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "jquery.form" %>
<script type="text/javascript"> var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
 </tr>

<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= member.name %> &amp; <%= member.sname %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', "javascript:", :onclick => "show_member(member.id)" %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_member_path(member) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'New Member', new_member_path %>

<div id="memberprofile">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_member(m_id) {
   var container = $j("#memberprofile");
        $j.ajax({
            url: '/members/get_member?mid=' + m_id, type: 'get', dataType: 'html',
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                container.html(data);
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

in your routes do something like:

```
resources :members do
  collection do
    get :get_member
  end
end
```

in your controller do:

```
def get_member
  @member = Member.find_by_id(params[:mid])

  render :partial => "member", :layout => false, :locals => {:member => @member}
end
```

in your _member.html.erb partial

```
<% unless @member.blank? %>
  <h1><%= @member.name %></h1>
<% else %>
   Record not found :(
<% end %>
```

Comment: The way is good but it will be better with the javascript in a separated file (see [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)). A good tutorial to how it should be achieve in Rails 3 [is here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=simonecarletti%2Fen)